# Can we have a condition to compare int and string data type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can i make a condition to compare `int` and `string`?

`int number;`
`string guess;`

`if (guess!=number){`
`cout <<"You lose";`
`else cout<<"You win!!";`

Comment: Convent the string to an `int`.  Take that value and any overflow indication and compare to the other `int`.

Comment: You can use `std::to_string` to convert `int` to `std::string` and then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `std::to_string` to convert the `int` to a `std::string` and then perform the comparison as shown below:

```
    int number = 5; std::string guess = "5";
//----------vvvvvvvvv------------------------->use std::to_string
    if(std::to_string(number)!= guess)
    {
        std::cout<<"not equal"<<std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"equal"<<std::endl;
    }
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6f0u6pH9yo)

Other alternative is to do the opposite. That is, convert the `std::string` to `int`(if possible) and then perform the comparison.

Comment: thank you. it does really work i am just started but is there a way around like int to string or we can just do "to_string" .

Comment: @Tri_Hai05 You're welcome. More information on `std::to_string` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). If you want to just write `to_string` without the `std::` then you can use a *using declaration*. See [live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/XqJywcXk_). In the mentioned live demo, note we don't have to write the `std::` because i have added a using declaration at the starting of the program.